# showing a text when the user denies camera access in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a cameraview and I want that if the user didn't accept the permission show a text and a button to go to settings however for some reason the text isn't shown.

Here's my code:

```
  Future<void> _checkAndProcessImage(InputImage inputImage) async {
    if (!_canProcess) return;
    if (_isBusy) return;

    // Check camera permission
    var status = await Permission.camera.status;
    print("status: $status");
  if (status.isDenied) {
    // Camera permission is not granted, request the permission
    await Permission.camera.request();
    status = await Permission.camera.status;

    if (status.isDenied) {
      // Camera permission is still not granted, show a custom text
      setState(() {
        _text = 'Camera permission is required to scan barcodes.';
      });
      return;
    }
  }

    // Camera permission is granted, proceed to process the image
    _isBusy = true;
    setState(() {
      _text = '';
    });
```

Why I don't see the status printed to the console? I use the permission_handler package.

Here's the rest of the code:

```
class _BarcodeScannerViewState extends State<BarcodeScannerView> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final BarcodeScanner _barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanner();
  bool _canProcess = true;
  bool _isBusy = false;
  CustomPaint? _customPaint;
  String? _text;
  bool _hasNavigated = false;
  var _cameraLensDirection = CameraLensDirection.back;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _canProcess = false;
    _barcodeScanner.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          _buildCameraView(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCameraView() {
    return DetectorView(
      title: 'Barcode Scanner',
      customPaint: _customPaint,
      text: _text,
      onImage: _checkAndProcessImage,
      initialCameraLensDirection: _cameraLensDirection,
      onCameraLensDirectionChanged: (value) => _cameraLensDirection = value,
    );
  }

  Future<void> _checkAndProcessImage(InputImage inputImage) async {
```

Comment: please show more of the code.

Comment: Sure, I added it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two line of code for ***debuggiung*** .

```
 if (!_canProcess) return;
    if (_isBusy) return;
```

Before ***_checkAndProcessImage***  . you should check the ***permission*** of
**Camera** and *Storage*.
Now ,check the permission status like:-

```
var status = await Permission.camera.status;
    print("status: $status");
```

IF Status is ***Granted***  , you should process the image .In other case , Show the ***error Text***.